# Handling big data in Mathematica 10

Tags: data

I have a huge amount of data saved in a `.txt` file (153 MB, ~7300000 rows). What I want in the end is a list like `{{14, 786.017296}, {28,786.017293},...}`. The file looks like this:

```
14  786.017296  
28  786.017293  
42  786.017290  
56  786.017287  
70  786.017282  
84  786.017279  
98  786.017276  
112 786.017271  
126 786.017270  
140 786.017267  
154 786.017262  
168 786.017260  
182 786.017256  
196 786.017252  
211 786.017250  
224 786.017247  
238 786.017243  
253 786.017240  
267 786.017236  
...
```

it's a set of two numbers as a $x$- and $y$-value. I tried different things like  [`ReadList[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReadList.html) or [`OpenRead[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpenRead.html). After [`OpenRead[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/OpenRead.html) I tried to seperate the numbers with [`Read[str, Number]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Read.html) within a [`For[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/For.html)-loop to save the pairs in a list. But the [`For[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/For.html)-loop needs much, much to long.

Is there any efficient way to handle this? Or do I have to shrink the data?

Comment: Have you tried `Import[yourfilename, "Table"]`?

Comment: Seems like "*huge* amount of data" is a bit of a fuzzy term here, when ["big (amount of) data"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_data) is associated with TB and more? ;-)

Comment: single digit TB is not considered "big data" any more..

Comment: @george2079:  ... being a case in point.

Answer (score 6):

for the record, `Readlist` is considerably faster than `Import`:

```
Export["test.dat", 
   Table[ {RandomInteger[1000], RandomReal[1000]} , {7300000}]];
f = OpenRead["test.dat"];
(data = ReadList[f, {Number, Number}];) // AbsoluteTiming // First
Close[f];
```

> 10.4757

```
(data2=Import["test.dat", "Table"];) // AbsoluteTiming // First
```

> 71.8076

```
data==data2
```

> True

Answer (score 4):

Your snippet of Data in file `1.txt` and in the same `dir` a Mathematica file `00.nb`

```
Import["1.txt", "Data"]
```

> {{14, 786.017}, {28, 786.017}, {42, 786.017}, {56, 786.017}, {70, 
>     786.017}, {84, 786.017}, {98, 786.017}, {112, 786.017}, {126, 
>     786.017}, {140, 786.017}, {154, 786.017}, {168, 786.017}, {182, 
>     786.017}, {196, 786.017}, {211, 786.017}, {224, 786.017}, {238, 
>     786.017}, {253, 786.017}, {267, 786.017}}